# Is there any way to override the double-underscore (magic) methods of arbitrary objects in Python?

Tags: python, object, magic-methods, getattr, getattribute

I want to write a wrapper class which takes a value and behaves just like it except for adding a 'reason' attribute. I had something like this in mind:

```
class ExplainedValue(object):
    def __init__(self, value, reason):
        self.value = value
        self.reason = reason

    def __getattribute__(self, name):
        print '__getattribute__ with %s called' % (name,)
        if name in ('__str__', '__repr__', 'reason', 'value'):
            return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
        value = object.__getattribute__(self, 'value')
        return object.__getattribute__(value, name)

    def __str__(self):
        return "ExplainedValue(%s, %s)" % (
            str(self.value),
            self.reason)
    __repr__ = __str__
```

However, the double-underscore functions don't seem to be captured with `__getattribute__`, for example:

```
>>> numbers = ExplainedValue([1, 2, 3, 4], "it worked")
>>> numbers[0]

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#118>", line 1, in <module>
    numbers[0]
TypeError: 'ExplainedValue' object does not support indexing
>>> list(numbers)
__getattribute__ with __class__ called

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#119>", line 1, in <module>
    list(numbers)
TypeError: 'ExplainedValue' object is not iterable
```

I would think the two above should end up doing this:

```
>>> numbers.value[0]
__getattribute__ with value called
1

>>> list(numbers.value)
__getattribute__ with value called
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Why is this not happening? How can I make it happen? (This might be a horrible idea to actually use in real code but I'm curious about the technical issue now.)

Comment: I think it's an optimisation. I seem to vaguely recall from having poked at the Python source that the interpreter's C structure that backs an object (or maybe a type) has special fields for `__magic__` functions. These are set when the object (or the class) is created. Whenever the interpreter internally needs to call those functions it can call it directly instead of doing a lookup through the `getattr` mechanism. (Obviously you should verify this by downloading the source and looking for where this structure is defined.)

Comment: If *all* you want is to set an additional attribute, there's no need for a wrapper class, you can set the attribute directly on the original object: `original_object.reason="because"`. But you probably know this already...

Comment: Actually, straight from the horse's mouth: http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#new-style-special-lookup - this behaviour and the rationale behind this is documented, it's not *just* an optimisation. (The docs for `__getattribute__` also link to this.)

Comment: @Nick I think the point of the question is *why* `__getattribute__()` doesn't get called (and log a message before the `TypeError`) when `__getitem__()` is being looked up.

Comment: @goncalopp: you can't do that for built-ins like booleans

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As millimoose says, an implicit `__foo__` call never goes through `__getattribute__`.  The only thing you can do is actually add the appropriate functions to your wrapper class.

```
class Wrapper(object):
    def __init__(self, wrapped):
        self.wrapped = wrapped

    for dunder in ('__add__', '__sub__', '__len__', ...):
        locals()[dunder] = lambda self, __f=dunder, *args, **kwargs: getattr(self.wrapped, __f)(*args, **kwargs)

obj = [1,2,3]
w = Wrapper(obj)
print len(w)
```

Class bodies are executed code like any other block (well, except `def`); you can put loops and whatever else you want inside.  They're only magical in that the entire local scope is passed to `type()` at the end of the block to create the class.

This is, perhaps, the only case where assigning to `locals()` is even remotely useful.

Comment: For extra credit, you could write a metaclass or factory function that creates the necessary methods automatically, given the type of the object you're wrapping.

Comment: that might be magic too far, but note that it _is_ a good idea for methods like `__hash__`, where Python does something special based on whether it exists at all.  (but maybe you shouldn't be proxying `__hash__` anyway.)

Comment: bummer! i've seen behind some of python's magic voodoo pixie dust and i am not so happy at what i've found =(. i'll live though

Comment: the beauty of python's magic voodoo pixie dust is that it's all only _slightly_ magical—except for the syntax, you could recreate all of it in python itself  :)

Answer (score 2):

For the sake of posterity, this is what I came up with:

```
class BaseExplainedValue(object):
    def __init__(self, value, reason):
        self.value = value
        self.reason = reason

    def __getattribute__(self, name):
        if name in ('value', 'reason'):
            return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
        value = object.__getattribute__(self, 'value')
        return object.__getattribute__(value, name)

    def __str__(self):
        return "<'%s' explained by '%s'>" % (
            str(self.value),
            str(self.reason))
    def __unicode__(self):
        return u"<'%s' explained by '%s'>" % (
            unicode(self.value),
            unicode(self.reason))
    def __repr__(self):
        return "ExplainedValue(%s, %s)" % (
            repr(self.value),
            repr(self.reason))

force_special_methods = set(
    "__%s__" % name for name in (
        'lt le eq ne gt ge cmp rcmp nonzero call len getitem setitem delitem iter reversed contains getslice setslice delslice' + \
        'add sub mul floordiv mod divmod pow lshift rshift and xor or div truediv' + \
        'radd rsub rmul rdiv rtruediv rfloordiv rmod rdivmod rpow rlshift rrshift rand rxor ror' + \
        'iadd isub imul idiv itruediv ifloordiv imod ipow ilshift irshift iand ixor ior' + \
        'neg pos abs invert complex int long float oct hex index coerce' + \
        'enter exit').split(),
)

def make_special_method_wrapper(method_name):
    def wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return getattr(self, method_name)(*args, **kwargs)
    wrapper.__name__ = method_name
    return wrapper

def EXP(obj, reason="no reason provided"):
    if isinstance(obj, BaseExplainedValue):
        return obj

    class ThisExplainedValue(BaseExplainedValue):
        pass
    #special-case the 'special' (underscore) methods we want
    obj_class = obj.__class__
    for method_name in dir(obj_class):
        if not (method_name.startswith("__") and method_name.endswith("__")): continue
        method = getattr(obj_class, method_name)
        if method_name in force_special_methods:
            setattr(ThisExplainedValue, method_name, make_special_method_wrapper(method_name))

    ThisExplainedValue.__name__ = "%sExplainedValue" % (obj_class.__name__,)
    return ThisExplainedValue(obj, reason)
```

Usage:

```
>>> success = EXP(True, "it went ok")
>>> if success:
        print 'we did it!'


we did it!
>>> success = EXP(False, "Server was on fire")
>>> if not success:
        print "We failed: %s" % (EXP(success).reason,)


We failed: Server was on fire
```

The explained values can be used interchangeably with those which they wrap:

```
>>> numbers = EXP([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], "method worked ok")
>>> numbers
ExplainedValue([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 'method worked ok')
>>> numbers[3]
4
>>> del numbers[3]
>>> numbers
ExplainedValue([1, 2, 3, 5], 'method worked ok')
```

It even fools `isinstance` (explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14529190/why-does-overriding-getattribute-to-proxy-a-value-screw-up-isinstance)):

```
>>> isinstance(EXP(False), bool)
True
>>> isinstance(EXP([]), list)
True
```