# Why does overriding __getattribute__ to proxy a value screw up isinstance?

Tags: python, class, inheritance, getattribute, new-style-class

Why does this happen?

```
class IsInstanceScrewer(object):
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value

    def __getattribute__(self, name):
        if name in ('value',):
            return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
        value = object.__getattribute__(self, 'value')
        return object.__getattribute__(value, name)

isinstance(IsInstanceScrewer(False), bool) #True
isinstance(IsInstanceScrewer([1, 2, 3]), list) #True
```

The class is definitely not an instance of bool, even though it attempts to wrap it.

Comment: Note that you need to change `('value')` to `('value',)` (with a comma), otherwise you have not created a tuple and `if name in ('value')` will be true if `name` is a substring of "value".

Comment: @BrenBarn: good catch. i used to have more items there in my initial example but reduced them to make it simpler and introduced a bug in the mean-time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`__getattribute__` is returning the `__class__` of the wrapped value instead of its own `__class__`:

```
>>> class IsInstanceScrewer(object):
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value

    def __getattribute__(self, name):
        print name
        if name in ('value',):
            return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
        value = object.__getattribute__(self, 'value')
        return object.__getattribute__(value, name)

>>> isinstance(IsInstanceScrewer(False), bool)
__class__
True
>>> isinstance(IsInstanceScrewer([1, 2, 3]), list)
__class__
True
```

This may be desired behavior or not depending on what you're doing.

Comment: Beat me to it.  I was just about to post this.  (but you did have a head start ;-)

Comment: As a side note, rather than a whole-sale overwriting of all attributes, sometimes it's a little nicer to define `__getattr__` which is only invoked if python fails to find the attribute through normal means.